# Which function in NativeDateAdapter decides the output value of datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, momentjs, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms

Which function in NativeDateAdapter decides the output value of datepicker?

Right now the output is in ISO Date format

"2017-10-31T18:30:00.000Z"

i want this output to be

"11/1/2017, 12:00:00 AM"

that is locale time

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-moment-adapter-example-bqvm2f

i have tried to implement custom dateAdaptor by extending nativeDateAdaptor

Comment: `nativedateadapter.useUtcForDisplay = false;` ?

Comment: @TahaPaksu wont it just handle display and not the output of it
The output is Date format which is timezone aware Ex. Wed Nov 15 2017 11:03:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: I don't know I didn't use it before, but when I looked at the source code, it showed that property. Why don't you use the format() method to format your output? https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/262c23b8402587a0137e88d79c2da177841c2ebc/src/lib/core/datetime/native-date-adapter.ts#L180

Comment: @TahaPaksu format is again for display string, String that shows up in datepicker but the output is always in UTC format and ISO when you stringify it

Comment: Oh, I now understand it. You want to set the timezone of the output.

Comment: @TahaPaksu i want to use datePicker for birthdate, and birthdate dont change according to time zone. When i send this "2017-10-31T18:30:00.000Z" timezone is cropped and hence date is one day less.

I Have update the question please have a look.

Comment: The Z character at last means the date is in UTC format. If you convert it to a date object, it gets the computer's timezone and converts it to the local timezone which makes the conversion.

Comment: @TahaPaksu thats the issue if is send "2017-10-31T18:30:00.000Z" to serve based on server's timezone it will parse this date and hence will get 31st in some countries and 1st in some. but my birthdate is 1st in any country i country i go. It cant be timezone aware

Comment: You should use UTC datetimes everywhere to prevent that. Both display and execution. If the nativedateadapter uses momentjs which doesn't seem so, you can use moment-timezone to set a default timezone.

Comment: there is something called momentDateAdapter which they gave in recent release. I will have a look at that

Comment: Ok that may solve your problem then.